# Using regex to select the text between two characters IF there is text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

I have this text:

`<a class="_f5rco33" href="/account-settings"><div class="_ojs7nk">Account</div></a>`

And I want to grab the word "Account", but when I use this regex

`">([^<]*)<"`

It returns `""` because `"settings"><div"` is the first valid instance.

My tags and text will change every time I run this, but I want to select what's between `>` and `<`, `IF` it is text, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Change your `*` to a `+`, so you end up with `">([^<]+)<`. I don't think you want the double quotes at the end either, since `Account` is followed by `</div>`, not by something like `<"div` which wouldn't be valid HTML anyway.

`*` means 0 or more matches, `+` means 1 or more. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) for some information about these 'quantifiers'.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/DeILv6/2/) is a working demo.